# A theme that has window colors like "dash transparent blur" on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: themes, unity-dash, window, transparency

I've been looking around for it , it's beautiful in my opinion , i haven't been able to find anything.
Does something like it exist ?

Thanks in advance.